# Does tsc 1.5 still need the --module flag?

Tags: typescript, tsc

[Typescript 1.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/07/20/announcing-typescript-1-5.aspx) added support for a [`tsconfig.json`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/1692) config file where one can specify things such as compiler options.

Here's a quip from the [blog post announcing 1.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/07/20/announcing-typescript-1-5.aspx):

> The compiler now supports ‘tsconfig.json’, a new file which allows you
>   to specify the files in your project and the compiler settings to use.

This made me think that adding the `--module` flag to the compiler wouldn't be necessary any more. But trying to compile a simple file that exports a class I get this:

```
tsctest.ts(1,14): error TS1148: Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.
```

When running `tsc` with `--module commonjs` everything works fine.

Here's the ts file:

```
//tsctest.ts
export class Empty {
}
```

And here's the `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
        "compilerOptions": {
                "target": "ES5",
                "module": "commonjs"
        }
}
```

My Typescript version is 1.5.3, `tsctest.ts` and `tsconfig.json` live in the same folder.

Answer (score 4):

TypeScript provides two ways to work with Modules
1. Internal Modules
2. External Modules

While the first option is generally used to break a TypeScript module across different .ts files(through which one can use a component of a module of a .ts in some other .ts file in the same module without any explicit import statement), the second options is used to explicitly import a module usually from a library available. It is External Modules for which you've to provide TypeScript compiler with module parameter.

So, in your code, the export syntax that you're using is for the first option (Internal Modules) for which you must put your code inside a module block.

You can refer the [documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules).

**EDIT**: This [article](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/05/stop-mixing-typescript-internal-and-external-modules/) resolves the common doubt that occurs while working with module.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json):

> When input files are specified on the command line, tsconfig.json files are ignored.

Run `tsc` without specifying any input files and it will work fine.